Least Squares Function Approximation and Convexity of Functions
I have been reading about Least Squares function approximation and am dealing with the following definition:
Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and let $W$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $C[a,b]$. A function $g \in W$ is the least squares approximation of $f$ with respect to $W$ when the value of $I = \int_{a}^{b} [f(x) - g(x)]^2 dx$ is minimum with respect to all other functions in $W$.
$g(x)$ could take on several forms depending on the type of approximation, it could be an arbitrary linear, polynomial, trigonometric function etc, with real valued coefficients $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n$. Treating each $a_i$ as a variable, upon evaluating our definite integral we now have a function $I(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$. Taking partials with respect to each $a_i$ and setting those equal to zero produces a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ variables. Solving such a system provides us with the values of the $a_i$ coefficients which minimize $I(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$. This leaves me with several questions.

For this linear system to be consistent and furthermore attain a unique solution, then the partial derivatives must be linearly independent. Are all partial derivatives linearly independent, if not, how does this method work? Does the structure of this function make the partial derivatives linearly independent in this situation?

I understand that taking the partials and setting them equal to zero we are solving for a critical point on the surface defined by $I(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$, but how can we be sure that whatever critical point we encounter will be a minimum and not a saddle point or maximum? Doing some reading, it seems to be that $I(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ is convex, since the degree of each $a_i \leq 2$ and as a result its Hessian matrix of partial derivatives is positive-semi definite (thus excluding maxima from the situation). How then, do we know then that the critical point is a global minimum and not a saddle point (assuming the linear system attains a unique solution).


Edit: Doing some further reading I've learned that strictly convex functions have a single global minimum and a Hessian matrix of only positive eigenvalues. So question number 2 could be simplified to, will $I(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$ always strictly convex? If so, why is this the case?

I think the least squares projection onto a finite-dimensional subspace is an orthogonal projection, which is therefore unique. I might be wrong on the details though.
